# What to read on how the philosophical understanding of the nature of philosophical topics, and being on- and off-topic, has evolved?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-language, terminology

My focus is to study the topic of *topic* itself and topicality, that is how a message, a question either a discussion can be on- or off-topic.

Which philosophers have been discussing this and what are seminal works?

So far I have found that this is less a linguistics topic but probably belongs more to the philosophy of language.

Related posts on SE sites:

- https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/34823/what-are-linguistics-foundations-of-how-a-message-can-be-on-topic
- https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/142675/which-scientific-discipline-studies-topics

Definitions of what topic and topicality are so far:

- "*[topicalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topicalization)*" which seems to be something else.
- in linguistics, topic is studied at sentence level
- in [sociolinguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_topic), there is a term "[discourse topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_topic)" which is probably going to the direction I want to look into: *The topic is what the discourse is about* though it feels like a tautalogy.

From what I can understand from the [general Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_language#Social_interaction_and_language) on language philosophy, studying what a topic is could belong to the sub-field reference theories? Or maybe social interaction, because what a current topic is could be also a *convention*?

Comment: You may want to have a look into semiotics and/or symbolic language, two technical terms that are about how language needs a referent and how it is possible to communicate about its identity in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps look into Yablo's Aboutness? https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691144955/aboutness